# How to make two independent changes through api

Tags: java, rest

I have a situation in which I have to update video details on facebook, that update needs two different calls, now my problem is

If any of the call fails, then what should I do?

I dont want to show user partially updated data, neither I want to retry as that might fail again if it failed already.

Only solution I think is to make a new call that will revert that previous call change, but that doesnt seems to be a nice solution.

Can someone suggest a better approach?

Comment: It's a difficult situration. Remember that your rollback (that reverts the first change) may also fail - sometimes due to things outside your control (maybe an internet connection that gets interrupted for a second, or the server goes down).

Answer (score 0):

It's a difficult situration.

Prior to making any API calls you should do anything you can to check for possible reasons why the calls may fail ahead of time - like missing authentication or authorization.

I agree that it is best practice not to show the user partially updated data, so you have a few options depending on what kind of failure you are up against.

If it fails with a network-like error you could just attempt a single retry to the 2nd endpoint.

Otherwise I'd recommend rolling back. If your rollback call fails, you should inform your user that some data has changed and could not be rolled back. If the error is a network error again you could create a queuejob to run later for rolling back the changes.

In any event, you should inform your user.